# pdf file encoding using jspdf with phonegap

Tags: android, ios, pdf, cordova, jspdf

I use jspdf on phonegap 3+ for android and ios 
I use the File plugin located to https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git#r1.0.1

I could create a pdf file with content but w/o images which does not work on a mobile platform (ios, android). The generated pdf file is corrupted.

Due to the API limitation with phonegap blob and blob builder are not supported on iOS. I can use it on android.

Assuming PdfOutput is provided by jsPDF.output()

```
var pdfdoc=new jsPDF();
// add content ....
var PdfOutput= pdfdoc.output();
```

and depending on whether or not blob is available, here are the 2 ways to create a file 
with a blob
version 1

```
bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(PdfOutput);
blob = bb.getBlob("application/pdf");    
writer.write(blob);
```

with this method the file is generated but  none of the accentuated letter is rendered properly for instance the character 'é' is rendered 'Ã©'

version 2

```
bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(PdfOutput);
blob = bb.getBlob("text/plain");    
writer.write(blob);
```

with this method the file is similar to version 1

without blob

```
writer.write(PdfOutput);
```

with this method again the file is similar to other version

the file content writen by writer.write is encoded in UTF8 but is pdf expected to contain only ascii data ?

Answer (score 0):

Not having the answer, but I do have a question. Why not use a cloud service and put the PDF generation in a NodeJS solution. Openshift lowest tier is free...
That way you don't have the differences of the platforms. And I even have used imagemagik on it, so images shouldn't be a problem.